# Really weird Javascript issue, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript

I am making a more "human" way to do math, and it's doing ok, however something is up with my code.

Basically, I'm telling the code to add 6 and 4 together and output it. It gives me what I'm expecting, somewhat. However the weird part about it, instead of printing straight just '10', it says:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, 10]
```

How can I just get it to return just '10'?

```js
function output(func) {
  console.log(func)
}
var dl = []
const read = str => {
  return str.split(' ').map(item => {
    dl.push(item.trim())
    if (dl.length >= 4) {
      const operator = dl.find(x => x.includes("add", "sub", "mul", "div"))
      const numbers = dl.filter(x => Number(x))
      switch (operator) {
        case "add":
          return numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));
      }
    }
  })
}
var main = read(
  `add 6 and 4`
)
output(main)
```

Comment: You're returning a call to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which is always an array

Comment: You're splitting the array into 4 parts. Then you map it. The first three times, `dl.length` is less than 4, so the result is undefined since your map callback doesn't return anything. You can shorten your code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uyvsonz0/ (note that String.includes doesn't support multiple search terms though)